# Display a List of Tuples in a C# cshtml View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, tuples

I have tried a few ways to get this Tuple list to display in my cshtml view as uploadModel.ErrorsList but have had no luck, this only displays the type of object the Errorslist (Tuple List int, string, string) is, the ErrorMessages (strings) do show the correct values on the screen. Here is my view:

```
@using Custom.Website.Areas.Custom.Models
@model Custom.Website.Areas.Custom.Models.ExcelUploadModel

<style type="text/css">
    #ExcelUploadForm {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div id="ExcelUploadForm" title="Excel Upload Results">
    <h2 id="requireReUpload" style="color:darkred">Please fix the following errors and reupload:</h2>
    <h2 id="uploadSuccess" style="color:green">Your Upload was successful. @Model.UploadedRowCount tickets updated.</h2>
    <div>Editable fields: Transporter Ticket #,Transporter, Driver, Truck, AFE #, Water Type, Quantity, Operator Job #, Lease.</div>
    <div>
        <ul id="uploadErrors"></ul>
    </div>
    <button class="backButton">Back</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("requireReUpload").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("uploadSuccess").style.display = 'none';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#uploadErrors').append('<li>@Model.ErrorMessage</li>');

        $('#uploadErrors').append('<li>@Model.ErrorsList</li>');

        //This function checks if the Error list contains any value.
        function excelUploadMessage() {
            // If Error List has nothing, display Success
            if ($('ul#uploadErrors:not(:has(li)')) {
                document.getElementById("uploadSuccess").style.display = 'block';
            }  // Otherwise, display reupload message
            else {
                document.getElementById("requireReUpload").style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
        excelUploadMessage();

    });

    $('.backButton').click(function () {
        window.history.back();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of :

```
$('#uploadErrors').append('<li>@Model.ErrorsList</li>');
```

create a for loop:

```
@foreach (var tupleErr in Model.ErrorsList){
<text>$('#uploadErrors').append('<li>@tupleErr.Item1 @tupleErr.Item2 @tupleErr.Item3</li>');</text>

}
```

sorry did not validate the syntax; but the idea is that you need to iterate over the list, then have an append jQuery statement for each item in the list. Keep in mind you can access the tuple items by the properties as "Itemx" .

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much mymo !